# generic member function pointer as a template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, variadic-templates

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class hello{
public:
    void f(){
        cout<<"f"<<endl;
    }
    virtual void ff(){
        cout<<"ff"<<endl;
    }
};

#define call_mem_fn(object, ptr)  ((object).*(ptr))

template<R (C::*ptr_to_mem)(Args...)> void proxycall(C& obj){
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    call_mem_fn(obj, ptr_to_mem)();
}

int main(){
    hello obj;
    proxycall<&hello::f>(obj);
}
```

Of course this won't compile at line 16, because the compiler doesn't know what `R`, `C` and `Args`, are. But there's another problem: if one tries to define those template parameters right before `ptr_to_mem`, he runs into this bad situation:

```
template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args, R (C::*ptr_to_mem)(Args...)> 
                             //  ^variadic template, but not as last parameter!
void proxycall(C& obj){
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    call_mem_fn(obj, ptr_to_mem)();
}

int main(){
    hello obj;
    proxycall<void, hello, &hello::f>(obj);
}
```

Surprisingly, g++ does not complain about `Args` not being the last parameter in the template list, but anyway it cannot bind `proxycall` to the right template function, and just notes that it's a possible candidate.

Any solution? My last resort is to pass the member function pointer as an argument, but if I could pass it as a template parameter it would fit better with the rest of my code.

EDIT:
as some have pointed out, the example seems pointless because proxycall isn't going to pass any argument. This is not true in the actual code I'm working on: the arguments are fetched with some template tricks from a Lua stack. But that part of the code is irrelevant to the question, and rather lengthy, so I won't paste it here.

Comment: It seems to me that you don't actually need variadic template parameters in this case. `proxycall()` isn't going to pass any arguments to the member function pointer invocation, so using variadic template parameters appears to make the problem more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your "call_mem_fn" #define doesn't actually provide parameters. So it won't work if Args is anything but empty. So how do you expect this to actually function?

Comment: The code in the question is just an example. The actual code will handle functions with an arbitrary number of arguments, and they will be retrieved from somewhere else (namely, a Lua stack). The metaprogramming glue code that fetches the arguments is already working, I won't paste it here as it's lengthy.

Comment: I was trying to give it a shot, but It think I lost track somewhere half-way through, so please ignore the answer if it's off.

Comment: FTR a variadic parameter pack doesn't have to be declared last, but then it can only be deduced, and not explicitly specified by the users with `<...>`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename ...Args>
R proxycall(T & obj, R (T::*mf)(Args...), Args &&... args)
{
    return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Usage:  `proxycall(obj, &hello::f);`

Alternatively, to make the PTMF into a template argument, try specialization:

```
template <typename T, T> struct proxy;

template <typename T, typename R, typename ...Args, R (T::*mf)(Args...)>
struct proxy<R (T::*)(Args...), mf>
{
    static R call(T & obj, Args &&... args)
    {
        return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
hello obj;

proxy<void(hello::*)(), &hello::f>::call(obj);

// or

typedef proxy<void(hello::*)(), &hello::f> hello_proxy;
hello_proxy::call(obj);
```

Comment: I always forget that when I'm in troubles with function templates, class templates are my lifeboat.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: Typically you implement your magic with a class template and use specialization, and in the end you add a little type-deducing *function* template so you don't have to spell out the template parameters. In this case, though, I don't really know how this helps, but perhaps this is enough to give you an idea.

Comment: Don't forget to deal with `const` member functions.  (But if you decide not to bother with `volatile` or `const volatile`, I wouldn't complain.)

Comment: how would it look like to deal with const member functions?

Comment: @user1810087:  The const-qualified member function pointer type is `R (T::*)(Args...) const`.

Comment: @Nikos: 1) The second template parameter is a non-type (= value) parameter. Just like in `template <int N> struct IntArray { int data[N]; };`. Just in our case the type of the non-type parameter is itself parametrised. 2) Partial specialization, I imagine.

Comment: As far as I understand, `template <typename T, T> struct proxy` could be simplified to `template <auto> struct proxy` in C++17. That worked for me, at least. That greatly simplifies the usage, especially for member functions with complex signatures!

Comment: @nilo Thank you for pointing out `auto`, which seems to [address exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38044251/1027706). Otherwise, without this feature one coulde use `decltype(hello::f)` to get rid of the signature complexity for first template parameter.

Answer (score 5):

In modern C++ one can use `template<auto>` and generic lambda-wrapper:

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template<auto mf, typename T>
auto make_proxy(T && obj)
{
    return [&obj] (auto &&... args) {
        return (std::forward<T>(obj).*mf)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}

struct R {};
struct A {};
struct B {};

struct Foo
{
    R f(A &&, const B &) { return {}; }
    //R f(A &&, const B &) const { return {}; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    make_proxy<&Foo::f>(foo)(A{}, B{});
    //make_proxy<static_cast<R (Foo::*)(A &&, const B &) const>(&Foo::f)>(std::as_const(foo))(A{}, B{});
    //make_proxy<static_cast<R (Foo::*)(A &&, const B &)>(&Foo::f)>(foo)(A{}, B{});
}
```

If there are overloadings one should to specify member function type explicitly as in commented code.