# C++ Delegate Exercise

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I've been working on making a small delegate template exercise to 1.) better myself, 2.) better understand template metaprogramming, and to 3.) possibly even use delegates for some event-driven programming (as I do not have access to standard libraries). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9779391/3780573) answer, something like the following can be implemented for functions:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename ...Args>
R proxycall(T & obj, R (T::*mf)(Args...), Args &&... args)
{
    return (obj.*mf)(args...);
}

proxycall(myobj, &MyObj::func);
```

It seems as if the compiler can figure out the return type, class type, and parameter types just by passing `myobj` and `&MyObj::func` into the template. Can the same method as above be used to create a delegate class (class that stores both a reference to an object and a pointer-to-member function)?

```
Delegate d(myobj, &MyObj::func); /* Preferred */
```

or

```
Delegate<myobj, &MyObj::func> d; /* Ok */
```

The following class is my Delegate class and it has the unfortunate side-effect of having to specify the `ReturnType` and the types of the `Parameters` in the corresponding member function. As I see above, the compiler can figure that stuff out. So, how can I have the compiler help me out?

```
template <class Class, typename ReturnType, typename ... Parameters>
class Delegate {
    public:
        typedef ReturnType (Class::*Method)(Parameters ... params);

        Delegate(Class& ref, Method m) : obj(ref), method(m) {}
        ReturnType operator()(Parameters ... params) { return (obj.*method)(params...); }
        ReturnType Invoke(Parameters ... params) { return operator()(params...); }
    private:
        Class& obj;
        Method method;
};

/* Usage */
Delegate<MyObj, void> d(myobj, &MyObj::func);
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
             ick
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in `proxycall` you should have `std::forward<Args>(args)...` instead of `args...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Delegate d(myobj, &MyObj::func);
```

Basically this would make `Delegate` independent from the type of the member function and its class.
Only the constructor template will know about the return type and the parameter types. The class does not. You will need type erasure to make the type of the delegate independent of the type of the internal function object - basically you would implement an [`std::function`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.cppreference.com%2Fw%2Fcpp%2Futility%2Ffunctional%2Ffunction&ei=nGlaVIjvD4bgsAS7o4HIBA&usg=AFQjCNGNfYkt6ld9GGVOUWmfb2S3yAaY8w&sig2=nSCVtbkcLaFc0bTGsglPCQ&bvm=bv.78677474,d.ZGU) whose implementation is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453145/how-is-stdfunction-implemented) (note that `function` is not fixed in terms of the return or parameter types).

If all you want is nicer syntax and less redundancy in the code, use a factory template:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename ...Args>
Delegate<T, R, Args...> make_delegate(T& obj, R (T::*mf)(Args...))
{
    return {obj, mf};
}
```

Which, when called with appropriate arguments, returns a Delegate with the corresponding type properly initialized.

```
auto deleg = make_delegate(myobj, &MyObj::func);
```

Comment: I don't think you want the `T` in `Delegate<R, T, Args...>`. That goes against everything you said immediately before it :)

Comment: @Barry I do want the `T` in there, I simply provided a factory for *his* class. It was at the wrong position though, thanks for the hint.

Comment: What about `Delegate<myobj, &MyObj::func> d`; Is this even possible? Can I pass a reference to a class and a pointer-to-member function as template parameters?

Comment: @thndrwrks No, this is not possible. Template non-type arguments must be constant expressions. `myobj` is surely not a constant expression. The address of the member function is, though. You could just pass the address of that member function and assign `myobj` through the constructor.

Comment: Ok that answers one question. Now how do I go about writing the template to accept such a function pointer? (I get so confused with template syntax).

Comment: That is, how do I get my template to recognize `Delegate<&MyObj::func>`?

Comment: @thndrwrks That is impossible. The template cannot deduce the type of its template argument. It has to be known in some form to `Delegate`.