# How can I pass a function that must be treated as a member function of template type

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

I have created the following simplified working example - where a `class Manager` takes a template argument and must invoke a member function `get_timestamp` against the template argument.

```
class Ex1 {
public:
    int timestamp;
    int get_timestamp() {return timestamp;};
    
};


template<typename T>
class Manager {
    
public:
    void process_data(T& type) {
        
        type.get_timestamp(); // 
    }    
    
};


int main()
{
    Manager<Ex1>();

    return 0;
}
```

I am looking for a solution where I can replace this `type.get_timestamp();` to something like `type.FUNC(args);` where the `FUNC` is passed into the class separately. Something similar to passing a lambda or `std::function` but the difference here is I must instruct the class to treat this "lambda"-like function as a member function of the template argument. Is that possible in C++. I am using c++20

Comment: You can pass the address of `get_timestamp()`, i.e. `&Ex1::get_timestamp`.

Comment: See [generic member function pointer as a template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779105/generic-member-function-pointer-as-a-template-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a member function pointer as a template argument:

```
template<typename T, int(T::*FUNC)()>
class Manager {
public:
    void process_data(T& type) {
        (type.*FUNC)();
    }
};

Manager<Ex1, &Ex1::get_timestamp> mgr;
```

Of course you can also pass it as a runtime argument to `process_data()`, or to the `Manager` constructor to store as a member variable.

Comment: Actually how do I store it as a variable in the class.

Comment: Define a type like `using MyFunc = int(T::*)();` in the class and then store `MyFunc func` inside your class instead of passing it as a template argument.